# Dynamics CRM 2013 Business process flow - Lead to Opportunity flow not automatic

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When trying to advance a business process flow from a Lead to an Opportunity, there is no Create + option as seen below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7XXV.png]

We have a custom entity that connects to an Opportunity and with no code changes, it actually works as expected.  Why is Lead to Opportunity busted?  Any ideas where to look?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qqV7.png]

Comment: This is only the case for the out-of-the-box BPFs that were first available in Polaris and have been kept the same since. They are "special" because of the Lead qualification process. You can roll your own that work more like the usual "Create" process for custom entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the default behavior in CRM. On BPF, when it comes to Lead and Opportunity, you have to click `Qualify` button on the command bar to qualify the Lead, an Opportunity will be created for that Lead. Also, if you don't specify an existing account/contact, an Account will be created based on Company Name in the Lead, a Contact will be created based on contact information in the Lead.

You can manually create an Opportunity and link it to the originating Lead. Then, in Lead form, when you click next stage there will be a list of related Opportunities.

Hope it helps!